# How to configure liferay to get correct ip address of user?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

Password rest mail currently sending private ip. I want below

$REMOTE_ADDRESS$ variable of liferay set public ip in password reset notification.

Internally liferay use request.getRemoteAddr(). How should i configure liferay so request.getRemoteAddr() give correct ip address.

Comment: Do you happen to use an Apache or nginx in front of your appserver?

Comment: Thanks Olaf We are using apache.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming, that you're using mod_proxy_http to forward requests from your Apache httpd to tomcat (or whatever appserver you use). This means, that there's a separate HTTP request, originating from your webserver. I'm assuming that this is the address that you see, no matter what request you handle.

One way to tackle this, is to use AJP as the forwarding protocol, instead of HTTP. You can do this by utilizing mod_proxy_ajp or mod_jk. This means that you can't encrypt the traffic between your web- and application server, however, it handles the remote host and other issues by default.

There might be other options, e.g. experimenting with adding the header `X-Forwarded-For`. I personally prefer AJP over HTTP as the forwarding protocol, that's why I never bothered to try the alternatives.

Basically, this does not involve Liferay at all: The remote host gets lost on the connection from Apache httpd to your appserver. Liferay just retrieves what the appserver tells it about the request.